# jquery UI .datePicker is not a function

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have seen many people asking this question and have tried it all (such as: [Why is jqueryUI datepicker throwing an error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713205/why-jqueryui-datepicker-throwing-an-error)).

Well i have an asp.net app; i am referring jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js which has all the jquery UI plugins with its css and jquery-1.6.2.min.js

Now when i say

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('._txtReviewDate').datePicker();
});
```

I get an error : $("._txtReviewDate").datePicker is not a function; on firebug. i checked whether the js files have loaded etc.

Please suggest how i can get it working.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to post a link to you page or may be the HTML code?

Comment: it is a huge file actually with master pages and web controls... i will try to reproduce the issue on a sample page and try it out..

Comment: Pretty strange your piece of code is `$('...')` and your error is `$j('...')`. Are your using `.noConflicts()` ?

Comment: hey sry.. while pasting i pasted this $j version... i was trying with noconflict.. btw my master page has some issue while loading this jquery ui library. need to sort out

Comment: Verify the order you include your javascript files: first jquery, then jqueryui. Note: `._xxxx` you should not prefix you class names with underscore, this is not really standard naming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an old jquery library added deep down somewhere long back which was just ignored over a period. Removing that resolved the issue.